# Convert number in format hours

Tags: javascript, react-native

How convert number in formart hours, exemple...

The API return object time: 185

He return for me 3 hours 10 minutes

```
const time = "185";

return <Text>You have, 3 hours 10 minutes</Text>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure of how 185 is converted to `'3 hours **10**minutes'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `185` represents the number of minutes: division (by 60) for hours, modulus for the remaining minutes

```js
const time = "185";
const [hours, minutes] = [Math.floor(time/60), time%60];
console.log(`You have, ${hours} hour(s) and ${minutes} minute(s)`);
```

Comment: But OP want to be 10 Minutes, you got 5. Your solutions looks right, but returns not the result he wants. I think OP needs to clarify his question.

Comment: Hence *If 185 represents the number of minutes*

Answer (score -1):

Try This may hope it will help you..

```
    let min=185;
    let time=new Date(min * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
    let timewithdate=new Date(min*60 * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    console.info(time)
    console.info(timewithdate)
```